# Automatically add title attribute to links in WordPress

Tags: title

If I link to an article on a website, is there a way to automatically include a title attribute with the value being the title of the linked page?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this works but it should,

```
function get_page_title($url){
        if( !class_exists( 'WP_Http' ) )
            include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC. '/class-http.php' );
        $request = new WP_Http;
        $result = $request->request( $url );
        if( is_wp_error( $result ) )
            return false;

        if( preg_match("#<title>(.+)<\/title>#iU", $result, $t))  {
            return trim($t[1]);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    add_filter('the_content','auto_add_title_to_link');

    function auto_add_title_to_link($content){
        $html = new DomDocument;
        $html->loadHTML($content); 
        $html->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
        //get all links
        foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        //make sure it dosent have a title
            if ($link->getAttribute('title') == '' || empty($link->getAttribute('title')))
                $links[] = $link->getAttribute('href');
        }
        //get title and add it
        foreach ($links as $link){
            $title = get_page_title($link);
            if (false !== $title){
                $replace = $link.' title="'.$title.'"';
                $content = str_replace($link,$replace,$content);
            }

        }
        return $content;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bit better (same concept but modified):

*Edit: New modified version on Github that supports images with links - https://github.com/wpexplorer/wpex-auto-link-titles/blob/master/wpex-auto-link-titles.php

```
function wpex_auto_add_link_titles( $content ) {

    // No need to do anything if there isn't any content
    if ( empty( $content ) ) {
        return $content;
    }

    // Define links array
    $links = array();

    // Get page content
    $html = new DomDocument;
    $html->loadHTML( $content );
    $html->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    // Loop through all content links
    foreach( $html->getElementsByTagName( 'a' ) as $link ) {

        // If the title attribute is already defined no need to do anything
        if ( ! empty( $link->getAttribute( 'title' ) ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        // Get link text
        $link_text = $link->textContent;

        // Save links and link text in $links array
        if ( $link_text ) {
            $links[$link_text] = $link->getAttribute( 'href' );
        }

    }

    // Loop through links array and update post content to add link titles
    if ( ! empty( $links ) ) {
        foreach ( $links as $text => $link ) {
            if ( $link && $text ) {
                $text    = esc_attr( $text ); // Sanitize
                $text    = ucwords( $text );  // Captilize words (looks better imo)
                $replace = $link .'" title="'. $text .'"'; // Add title to link
                $content = str_replace( $link .'"', $replace, $content ); // Replace post content
            }

        }
    }

    // Return post content
    return $content;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpex_auto_add_link_titles' );
```